# How to use nack on Pubsub properly?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I am gathering messages from a topic in Pubsub. The main idea is that for every message that I get do some logic (insert some stuff in DB).
My question is this.

After I do the logic I want to put a `message.ack()` method for telling pubsub "ok, this message its done!".
My problem is that I want to go for the "dark side" and if anyone fails go to my catch on the `message.nack()` to say "Ok pubsub, we have a problem, I DONT acknowledge this message so lets keep going with the rest"

But it keeps throwing this error and don't continue with the others messages.

What can i do?

Controller:

```
  @EventPattern('topicName')
  async extractMessageTopic(msg: Message) {
    try {
      console.log("--Iniciando--");
      await this.appService.extractMessageTopic(msg)

      
      msg.ack() //Acknoledge the message
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error primera capa!", error);
      msg.nack()//If any error, dont acknoledge
    }
  }
}
```

Service:

```
  async extractMessageTopic(msg: Message) {
    const buf = Buffer.from(msg.data)
    const dataObject: any = JSON.parse(buf.toString())
    console.log("Mensaje -> ", dataObject);
    console.log("------------");


    //Inserto En shipment
    //const shipId = await this.shipmentRepositoryService.insert(dataObject)

    //Inserto en Orders

    //Inserto en Lines
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implemented logic on your use case where a message is received and processed and if it errors out you are doing `nack()` will result to an infinite re delivery of messages. The behavior of [nack()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/pubsub/latest/Message.html#nack) is it will just redeliver the message continuously until it is not acked.

> nack()
>
> Removes the message from our inventory and schedules it to be redelivered.

What I could suggest is to set up a [dead-letter topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures). What it does is, if a message was not acked in the set deadline it will retry for a number of times. If it hits the maximum retry attempts, the message will be sent to the dead-letter topic and messages will be purged when the set message retention limit is met.

Comment: amazing info, i read the nack method but i really dont fully understand it until now.